# Program to make a simulation of the program I'm looking for

Tags: software-development, simulation, gui-builder

Look at what we are doing here.  Instead of me trying to use words to describe the software I am looking for, WHAT IF I made a simulation of the software I am looking for … that you could play with to know just what I'm looking for?

That's the software I'm looking for. I'd SHOW YOU but …

This may be in the family of Rapid Application Development (RAD), however there seems to be a sub class of these known as "Low Code development tools" … which actually develop working apps and forms.  This, however, would be the wrong focus.  Low code tools sacrifice flexibility for functionality.

The software I am looking for removes functionality in order to be more flexible.

And if flexibility comes through minimal coding (scripting?) then that would work.

[Mockplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockplus) is a very interesting offering, and I think is close … however it seems rather widget-based.  In other words, your GUI simulation looks like their widgets.

The software I am looking for would have to be very flexible in the STYLE aspects of a GUI … where the ability to appear like *anything*, and behave like *anything* is the right direction … from crazy animated glowing light things to super futuristic HUD-like elements.  Very strong, explicit control of graphics elements a must (like controlling the alpha for any design element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be Axure RP.   (http://www.axure.com/)

It's not quite perfect but has the most control/flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is software development prototyping software or "Rapid Application Development" this will allow you to quickly put together the User Interface  or User eXperience *UI or UX prototype* to give to potential users to see if you have captured their design requirements.

A lot depends on the area that you are considering are you looking at:

- Desktop Applications for a Single OS
- Desktop Applications for Multiple OSes
- Web Applications
- Mobile Applications
- Database based
- Industrial Control
- Games

and more depends on you budget and level of programming experience.

A few possibilities if you are on a tight budget:

1. If you have some coding skill and are looking at multiple OSes - Look at [Python](http://www.python.org) + one of [tkInter](http://www.tkdocs.com/), [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/), [Kivi](http://kivy.org/) or [QT](http://qt-project.org/) any of which will let you get started on quickly designing and implementing your user interface.
2. If you have some coding skills and are aiming at web development [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org) is well worth a look.
3. If you are looking to prototype gaming then try [Python](http://www.python.org) + [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html)
4. If you have little or no coding skills and are aiming to target mobile & web applications then take a look at [Mockplus](http://www.mockplus.com/).

All of the above *with the exception of Mockplus* are Free, Gratis & Open Source, QT has some licence restrictions if you are doing commercial work. Mockplus is available Free (Gratis) or Pro (currently $119/pa).

If you have a larger budget then there are a lot of tools available to you but you will have to narrow down what you are looking for in terms of targets, how much fidelity and performance you need your skills and how much work you are prepared to do.

Comment: Hi Steve, that's interesting.  Yes, I can narrow.

Comment: Windows, specifically, unlimited budget.  Don't want to code at all... but can.  The software I'm looking for can be used by an executive assistant, let's say.  Smart. Can make the most kick butt power points, but not a programmer.  The idea is to pay more in order to have to do less in a flexible tool that delivers a high quality result.

Comment: @Ryder It might be worth adding the above to your question but Mockplus definitely sounds like the sort of thing that you are looking for.